# Creating a directive and Isolating scopes in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please view my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjKHF/1/)

I have a fairly wonkey interaction that on a div mouseenter/mouseleave toggles a input checkbox on/off.  If said checkbox is set true, it then sets a focus of an adjacent input text field.

**I would like to isolate this interaction into a directive that will allow me to duplicate without conflict.**
i've color coated the boxes for reference

```
<body ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="span2 box red" leave-edit="uncheckInputBox(false)" enter-edit="checkInputBox(true)">hover</div>

    <span class='span8'>
      <p>red</p>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked">
      <input xng-focus='isChecked' ng-model="editingInput">
      {{isChecked}}
      {{editingInput}}
    </span>

  </div>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="span2 box blue" leave-edit="uncheckInputBox(false)" enter-edit="checkInputBox(true)">hover</div>

    <span class='span8'>
      <p>blue</p>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked">
      <input xng-focus='isChecked' ng-model="editingInput">
      {{isChecked}}
      {{editingInput}}
    </span>

  </div>



  </div>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('ngApp', [])

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.isChecked = false;

    $scope.$watch('isChecked', function(newV){
      newV && $('#name').focus();
    },true);

    $scope.checkInputBox = function(val) {
      $scope.isChecked = val;
    };

    $scope.uncheckInputBox = function(val) {
      $scope.isChecked = val;
    };

}]);

app.directive('xngFocus', function() {
    return {



      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch(attrs.xngFocus, 
         function (newValue) { 
            newValue && element.focus();
         },true);
      }
    };
});
app.directive('leaveEdit', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
    scope.$apply(attrs.leaveEdit);
  });
  };
});

app.directive('enterEdit', function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    scope.$apply(attrs.enterEdit);
  });
  };
});
```

**css**

```
.box {
  height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange interaction, but okay. You need to not use the same scope for each directive since you want them to be isolated. 
I just did this by creating a scope for a directive that has the shared template.

```
app.directive('why', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, elt, attrs) {
             //setup in here
        }, ...
```

A few other things:
Don't include angular through external resources and in the framework section of fiddle. It runs angular over your dom twice and will behave strangely.
Also there are `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` directives in angular so you don't need to implement those.

The updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VjKHF/2/)

Hope this helped!